# Chart.js is not respecting my container dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I'm trying to create a line chart using the Chart.js library.  I've got a `div` with dimensions 600px wide by 250px height, and from what I've read the library is meant to create a line chart using these parent dimensions.

The following shows my HTML element:

```
<div style="width:600px;height:250px">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var data = {
                    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "My First dataset",
                            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                        },
                        {
                            label: "My Second dataset",
                            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                        }
                    ]
                };
                var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
                new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
                    responsive:true
                });
});
```

And this shows the issue I'm having in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr88htnp/ (Note that the rendered chart has dimensions of 600x300)

Comment: Are you using any external CSS associated with #myChart?

Comment: no, you can see the issue in the jsfiddle, there's literally no CSS apart from the inline style I used to highlight it

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to set the option `maintainAspectRatio` to false

```
....
new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    responsive:true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
});
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3cxeyLc8/

Comment: this is now an outdated way to create charts as of chart.js version 2

Comment: Ahhh finally, nearly a dozen of topics and no one mentioned this aspect ratio. Good job !

Comment: @AFriend maybe so, but the `maintainAspectRatio` option is still available, and fixes the problem.

Comment: This still works and is the way to go, I think.

Answer (score 17):

Add the following CSS to #myChart:

```
 <canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting width and height 100% work for me

```
<LineChart :chart-data="chartData1" :options="options" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
```